# What have philosophers said about the consequences of being in patriarchal or matriarchal societies?

Tags: political-philosophy

Families or societies can be roughly divided into [patriarchal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarchy) or [matriarchal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchy) families or societies.

What have philosophers said about the consequences (economic ,social, political, sexual etc) of being born in matriarchal or patriarchal families or societies ?

Comment: Please add some context and references. Why is the distinction from your first sentence useful and suitable?

Comment: They are not philosophies...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  When Eastern and Western or High class and low class philosophies can exist then why not matriarchal and patriarchal philosophy?

Comment: Sociology or anthropology question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engels book "The Origin of the Family, Private Property and the State" answers all related questions; In his book you can see how economic and political state of societies are related to the patriarchal or matriarchal model. By simplifying things, what he says is that the patriarchal model was established basically due to property inheritance. What is evident from historical facts is that the indigenous people - all around the world - had basically a matriarchal model; in these societies property was somehow shared among larger groups of people.